# Can title tag be used as attribute in html tag?

Tags: html

Is it valid to use title as an attribute of the html tag, example:   ? 
W3C says this is supported in HTML5, however I am not getting the expected result on Chrome 38.x.

Comment: <html title="xyx"> 
vs
<html>
<title ="xyx">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the title attribute, it is merely used to define extra information about an element which the browser will typically render as a tool tip when you hover over.  It is not intended to be used to set your page title, the title tag is still used for that.  While, according to the HTML5 spec, the title attribute is valid on the html tag (it's valid on all tags) I'd wager it's pretty useless.