# Can I use a custom built Angular component as a placeholder for an Input field

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm working on a project. I have created a custom `month-picker` component in `Angular 6` from the scratch (*because I'm not allowed to outsource any 3rd party library not even `bootstrap`, `fontawesome` or `primeng`) and for that I want a simple text field inside which I want to show a simple calendar icon. I tried few solutions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag) is most relevant but they are using `AngularJS`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-a-custom-attribute-to-an-html-tag) is also somewhat different. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171035/can-title-tag-be-used-as-attribute-in-html-tag) is also not very useful. Here is my code. I also created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodingMonk/pen/gObPYrb).

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<our-icon class="icon-our-calendar"></our-icon>
<input class="input-field" type="text">
```

**Note:** `<our-icon>` is my organisation's own library of icons. I'm not allowed to go beyond that.

I was trying [this](https://codepen.io/CodingMonk/pen/gObPYrb) on CodePen but using some hex code for the icon. Is there anyway I can add `our-icon` tag as a placeholder to the input field like this:

```
<input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="<our-icon class="icon-our-calendar"></our-icon>">
```

I know this is completely wrong but just wanted to give you an idea what I actually mean.

But first I want to ask is it even doable or I'm simply wasting everyone's time.
Please give me some direction.

Comment: So you need to implement month picker which will have icon from your organization library, right?

Comment: @Plochie, Yes, exactly. I also asked for hex code of their calendar icon but they say no you do it using tag only. :-(

Comment: So in input field you want to show some icon? icon from library

Comment: @Plochie. Yes. You got it right. That icon is available to me only in the form of a tag. It would be much easier it was a hex code.

Comment: @Plochie. Am I making any sense ?

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a `css` problem. Treat icon and input as different elements rather than incorporating with each other.

Make `position: absolute` for icon and apply padding according to size of icon so that input start after the icon.

**CSS**

```css
input {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    height: 25px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <app-our-icon class="input-icon"></app-our-icon>
  <input>
</div>
```

[Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpb8dx)